# Filtering on a LEFT JOINED column

Tags: mysql, left-join

Is there a more efficient way to filter on a joined table as in the following example? Or is this a fine approach? This query returns the desired results, but I am an amateur at MySQL.

I have indexes on products.id, product_details.product_id and product_details.value

```
SELECT p.id 
  FROM products p
  LEFT 
  JOIN product_details d
    ON d.product_id = p.id
 WHERE d.value = 1 
    OR p.id = 4
```

Simplified structure as follows:

products table

```
product_id (PRIMARY KEY) | name
--------------------------------
1                        | Shirt
2                        | Shoes
3                        | Dress
4                        | A product with no corresponding details row
```

product_details table

```
product_id (PRIMARY KEY) | value
---------------------------------
1                        | 1
2                        | 23
3                        | 32
```

Comment: Define "bad practice."  Can you add sample data which helps to explain your question?

Comment: Does your current query return results like how you want it to?

Comment: Updated my question. Yes, the query returns the results as desired. I am just trying to avoid writing queries that are inefficient.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT products.id 
FROM products LEFT JOIN
     product_details
     ON product_details.product_id = products.id
WHERE product_details.value = 1 OR products.id = 4;
```

This is not a bad practice.  I do think the query is easier to follow using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM products p
WHERE p.id = 4 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM product_details pd
              WHERE pd.product_id = p.id AND pd.value = 1
             );
```

In addition `EXISTS` makes it clear that you don't want to return duplicates if there are duplicate matching rows in `product_details`.

If performance is you main consideration, then `EXISTS` is probably your best choice, with an index on `product_details(product_id, value)`.

Comment: I wouldn't use the exists keyword since the asker is looking for effeciency.......

Comment: @YunfeiChen . . . Then you are wrong.  With an index, `EXISTS` should be as fast or faster than any other alternative method you might consider.  I would retract the downvote, given that it is based on ignorance.

Comment: https://www.java67.com/2017/06/difference-between-correlated-and-non-correlated-subquery-in-sql.html#:~:text=That's%20why%20sometimes%20only%20solution,faster%20than%20a%20correlated%20subquery. And also https://www.google.com/search?q=is+exists+a+correlated+subquery&oq=is+ex&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l3j69i60l3.11063j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Proves you otherwise

Comment: @YunfeiChen the EXISTS clause here is actually fine. Although it is a subquery, he is using the product_id in the WHERE clause (presumably the clustered index) so this should be just as fast as a JOIN using the same key.

Comment: @YunfeiChen . . . Although you can't believe everything you read in books, you should read the part "When a correlated subquery is good" in "High Performance MySQL".  You can read the relevant part here (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html), but perhaps you should buy the book -- in such a way that the author gets royalties.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of notes:

1. As a rule of thumb, a UNION ALL statement performs better than an OR operator. Also, this helps clear up the query.
2. Using both an implicit JOIN and a predicate in the WHERE clause on the same table can get you into trouble - especially if you're using a LEFT OUTER JOIN (the predicate in the WHERE clause has precedence over the LEFT OUTER JOIN).

Seems like you always want to pull back any records that has a products.id = 4, and also any products that have a product_details.value = 1. This seems like two separate queries to me, and splitting it would probably make it easier to maintain in the future.

```
SELECT 
    p.id 
FROM
    products p
WHERE
    p.id = 4

UNION ALL

SELECT
    p.id 
FROM
    product_details pd
JOIN
    products p
    ON
        p.id = pd.product_id
WHERE
    pd.value = 1
```

Source: https://bertwagner.com/posts/or-vs-union-all-is-one-better-for-performance/

Comment: Although it is slightly more effecient it also looks twice as long, not sure how often you would want to do this??

Comment: @YunfeiChen , instead of being critical to every answer, why don't you answer with the most efficient query you can do - based on your experience.